# Animate a css property between components

Tags: svelte

I'm building a navbar, and the page title that is selected is underlined. However, I would really like to animate this as well, so that the underline moves between the page titles as you select them.

I've been reading up on svelte animations, and I guess this would be simple if I define the underline as a separate component. I would prefer to have it as a css property on the title component though, as this creates a more logical coupling.

It seems like a regular fade in and out would be easy, but I wonder if it's possible to make the underline actually move between the titles?

I hope my explanation was clear - thank you

Comment: While it would be doable for two elements next to each other, once you go from A to C (with B) between you will need a separate element to do so.  You can use a pseudo element on the navbar itself though.